# R plot conditional color (with more than one condition)

Tags: r, if-statement, plot, colors

I'm trying to produce a plot in R with data points colored if they meet condition X AND condition Y **OR** condition Z AND condition Y.

I can produce a graph for half of this argument -- ie: color if condition X and Y are met.

```
plot(mydata$Mean, mydata$log2FoldChange, cex=0.3, pch=20, 
col=ifelse(mydata$foldChange>2 & mydata$pval<0.05, "red", "black"), log="x", 
xlab="mydata$mean", ylab="mydata$log2foldchange")
```

which looks like:[this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fMOY2.png)

Ideally, I'd like the bottom half of the graph to be colored for similiar conditions: pval<0.05 and foldChange<0.2.

I've tried:

`plot(mydata$Mean, mydata$log2FoldChange, cex=0.3,pch=20, col=ifelse(mydata$foldChange>2 & mydata$padj<0.05, "red", "black"), col=ifelse(mydata$foldChange<0.2 & mydata$padj<0.05, "blue", "black") log="x", xlab="mydata$mean", ylab="mydata$log2foldchange")`

But it throws an error:

> Error: unexpected symbol in "plot(mydata$Mean, mydata$log2FoldChange,
>   cex=0.3,pch=20, col=ifelse(mydata$foldChange>2 & mydatar$padj<0.05,
>   "red", "black"), col=ifelse(mydata$foldChange<0.2

I'm just not sure how to include an "or" statement in R.  Thanks for any help, I'm still very new to R!

Comment: Something like `c("red","black")[with(mydata, (condition1) | (condition2) ) + 1]` maybe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about :

```
col=ifelse(mydata$padj<0.05, ifelse(mydata$foldChange>2,"red", ifelse(mydata$foldChange<0.2 , "blue", "black"), "black"), "black")
```

Comment: Great! Had to rearrange it a little but something similiar worked perfect: 
`plot(mydata$Mean, mydata$log2FoldChange, cex=0.3, pch=20, col=ifelse(mydatar$foldChange>2 & mydata$padj<0.05, "red", ifelse(mydata$foldChange<0.2 & mydata$padj<0.05, "blue", "black")), log="x")`